# Sticky Tabs Attaching To Specific Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have some sticky tabs that I am using to automatically pin to the top of the content area when scrolling so the user always knows that category they are in. You can see this here http://www.codeclimb.com/menus3/index2.html as you scroll the tab will stick the top. I am achieving this with the following javascript

```
function stickyTitles(stickies) {

this.load = function() {

          stickies.each(function(){

                var thisSticky = jQuery(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');
                    thisSticky.parent().height(thisSticky.outerHeight());

                jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos', thisSticky.offset().top);

          });
    }

    this.scroll = function() {

          stickies.each(function(i){                

                var thisSticky = jQuery(this),
                      nextSticky = stickies.eq(i+1),
                      prevSticky = stickies.eq(i-1),
                      pos = jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos');

                if (pos <= jQuery(window).scrollTop()) {

                      thisSticky.addClass("fixed");

                      if (nextSticky.length > 0 && thisSticky.offset().top >= jQuery.data(nextSticky[0], 'pos') - thisSticky.outerHeight()) {

                            thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", jQuery.data(nextSticky[0], 'pos') - thisSticky.outerHeight());

                      }

                } else {

                      thisSticky.removeClass("fixed");

                      if (prevSticky.length > 0 && jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos')  - prevSticky.outerHeight()) {

                            prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");

                      }

                }
        });         
}
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var newStickies = new stickyTitles(jQuery(".followMeBar"));

    newStickies.load();

    jQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {

          newStickies.scroll();

    });
 });
```

However you can see that this is designed to stick the tabs to the very top of the browser and not right below the header. Currently I have applied a margin-top to the CSS to make the followbar stick to the bottom of the div I want it to (the "now serving" section) but you can see that it takes longer for the title tab to snap to the next category because it is really doing it when it hits the top of the browser.

So as each time it passes the "now serving" section I want it to snap the tab there.

Any fix on how I can make it work to the div I want specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by accounting for the height of the header in the `$(window).scroll` event like so:

```
    this.scroll = function() {

          stickies.each(function(i){                

                var thisSticky = jQuery(this),
                      nextSticky = stickies.eq(i+1),
                      prevSticky = stickies.eq(i-1),
                      pos = jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos');

                if (pos - 120 <= jQuery(window).scrollTop()) {

                //**120px is the height of the header  

                      thisSticky.addClass("fixed");

                      if (nextSticky.length > 0 && thisSticky.offset().top - 120 >= jQuery.data(nextSticky[0], 'pos') - thisSticky.outerHeight()) {

                            thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", jQuery.data(nextSticky[0], 'pos') - thisSticky.outerHeight() - 120);

                      }

                } else {

                      thisSticky.removeClass("fixed");

                      if (prevSticky.length > 0 && jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos')  - prevSticky.outerHeight()) {

                            prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");

                      }

                }
        });         
}
```

P.S. When can I buy a chicken kabob drink? :)

Comment: This worked! Thanks a bunch and good fix! You can have one on me anytime lol.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the line:
`if (pos <= jQuery(window).scrollTop())`
To something like this:
`if (pos <= jQuery(window).scrollTop() + offset)`
Where `offset` is equal to the height of the header.